# Clang format breaks separation of big numbers with apostrophes

Tags: c++, clang-format, bignum, automated-refactoring

In c++14 we can use `'` to write big numbers in a more readable way, like this: `2'000'000'000'000'000'000`. But my clang-format turns it into this: `2 '000' 000 '000' 000 '000' 000`. What should I do to avoid that?

Comment: Quotes in integer literals was added in C++14.  Does your compiler support those C++ features?

Comment: I don't get how it's connected to the compiler, but yes, it suports c++14.

Comment: Are you using quote format in c++ code itself or in data read / written by c++?

Comment: In c++ code itself

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following to your `.clang-format` file:

`Standard: c++14` (or greater)